# How to set up replication of motion controllers using blueprints

Tags: replication, unreal-engine4, virtual-reality, multiplayer, unreal-engine5

I have a Shared Spaces project for UE5.1.
I created a new character and added motion controllers to it. Lasers are attached to the motion controllers. Lasers are calculated based on the line trace in the character blueprint. The lasers are displayed differently on the listen server and the client.

The server does not see the hand movement made by the client.

When pointing the laser at the "cube" object, the character can take it.
The server does not see as the client’s interaction with the object.

[image: pov: server]

1. I set Replicate component Motion controllers to "true"
2. I create variable "transform" with RepNotify and set current transform of motion controller at tick
   [variable "transform"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYSzN.png)